# Car bounces at 40+ mph after new tires added

Tags: tires, struts

As stated in the headline, my car is bouncy when driving at speeds around 40mph or over (not sure when it tapers, I drive almost exclusively within city limits). I had new tires installed less than a week ago and this issue was not present with the old set. What gives? I brought it back to them, they mentioned maybe it was the struts, after realigning it. Could the new set prompt an issue with the struts? It’s odd to me that if they’ve been weak this whole time there were no prior indicators before the new tires.

Comment: Did you have the tires balanced when you had them installed. If you paid for them to be balanced then tell the shop they are not balanced and they need to do it right. What do you mean "realigning it" An alignment is not part of a new tire purchase unless it was out of alignment and that caused the old tires to wear unevenly. **More info is needed**.

Comment: Make and model of car, year of car, and mileage would be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @AlaskaMan - While an alignment is not *required* when you put new tires on your vehicle, it is something *which should be done* to protect the investment of the new tires. I sure as heck don't want to wear out a brand new set of tires after just putting them on the vehicle. A bad alignment can do irreparable damage to new tires within a few hundred miles. Getting the alignment done (or at least checked) *is just the smart thing to do*.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I was trying extract more info from the OP such as why there may have been a need for an alignment. I just inspect my tires for uneven wear And i can feel unusual steering or tracking  issues.  I can see if the tread is wearing unevenly. If i see signs of uneven wear or feel problems then i can be confident that it is wise to pay for an alignment check. That's me, just saying what i am ok with. **It is important to have a properly aligned steering and suspension system**.

Answer (score 1):

I would put money on the fact the tires are out of balance. As long as the shop did the balancing in the first place, take it back to them and tell them to check their work. Something is wrong there and they should be the ones to fix it on their dime. If there was no issue before with the struts/shocks, there should be no problem with them after the tire change.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that one of the new tires is slightly out-of-round. This is much less likely, however, than an unbalanced tire. In any event, back to the shop is right thing to do.